# Does Lync Server 2013 support UCWA 2.0

Tags: lync-2013, ucwa

We need to integrate with a partner that runs Lync Server 2013, including the August 2016 cumulative update.

I would like to use UCWA **version 2.0**, which is well documented here: https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/whats-new-ucwa

So far I couldn't find any release notes or documentation that confirms that Lync Server 2013 supports UCWA 2.0, and if it does - which updates are required.

Comment: You will want to move to Skype for Business Server 2015 to take advantage of 2.0 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following:

- In general Lync Server 2013 CU1 and above used UCWA 1.0.* (Lync 2013 RTM didn´t have UCWA) while Skype for business Server 2015 used UCWA 2.0.*
- In coexistence mode (Lync 2010 and Skype for Business 2015) you must point the Autodiscover CNAME (Lyncdiscover. and LyncDiscoverinternal.) to a Skype for Business Server 2015 pool in order support custom UCWA 2.0 application development (as written [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/blob/master/Skype/UCWA/RootURL.md)). But that's for Lync 2010 which do not have any UCWA on its frontend server as written [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/270f79b2-12e2-488f-951e-82ead67fcd0e/ucwa-on-lync-2010?forum=ucwebapi).
- A Lync 2013 mobile client used also the UCWA (as mentioned [here](http://www.msxfaq.de/lync/mobile/lync2013mobileios.htm) or [here](http://blog.schertz.name/2013/07/understanding-lync-2013-mobility/)) and is compatible with Skype for Business.
- The UCWA 1.0 Code samples, Get started, What is this API?, Core features and Reference URLs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162980.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) all points now to the UCWA 2.0 links.

lead to the point that this should work.